# Loop though array and Displaying the elements only after click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dom, addeventlistener

I want to loop though  the array (array) and display the elements one by one only after clicking the button (bt). When i run this code it shows only the last element of the array (i.e honda). Please help me out

```js
var hints = document.querySelector(".hint");
var array = ["Car", "bmw", "mercy", "porsche", "hyundai", "jeep", "honda"];
var bt = document.querySelector("button");
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    bt.addEventListener("click", function(){
        hints.textContent = array[i];
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Password</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="password.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="hint"></h1>
        <button type="button" name="button">Cick me</button>
        <script src="password.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime, it's showing `honda` when you click on the button because at the time the click event is triggered the value of i is `6`.

So,always when you click, it will always show array[6] value, which is 'honda'.

Anyways, please try the below, it should work:

```
let hints = document.querySelector(".hint");
let array = ["Car", "bmw", "mercy", "porsche", "hyundai", "jeep", 
"honda"];
let bt = document.querySelector("button");
let count = 0;

bt.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hints.textContent = array[count];
    console.log('clicked!!');
    count++;

    if (count > array.length) {
        console.log('no more values in the array!!');
        return false;
    }
})
```

I have also create a `codepen` for it. You can also have a look:
https://codepen.io/vishalkaului/pen/EbyjML

Answer (score 0):

There is no `for` loop need. Keep a track of your count, and display the next one on click. See the edited code below:

```js
var hints = document.querySelector(".hint");
var array = ["Car", "bmw", "mercy", "porsche", "hyundai", "jeep", "honda"];
var bt = document.querySelector("button");
var count = 0;
    bt.addEventListener("click", function(){
       if (count < array.length) {
             hints.textContent = array[count];
            count++;
       }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Password</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="password.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="hint"></h1>
        <button type="button" name="button">Cick me</button>
        <script src="password.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But it prints all the elements in a array at a time, but i want it to print one by one as i go on clicking.

Comment: @user8887678 oh, I've edited my answer, to answer that now